# Variable is defined but GraphQL cannot find it

Tags: graphql

Just learning GraphQL, I have this query:

```
query OrganizationForFacebook($organization: String!, $repository: String!) {
  organization(login: $organization) {
    name
    url
    repository(name: $repository) {
      name
      forkCount @include(if: $withFork)
    }
  }
}
```

and I have defined my variables as such:

```
{
  "organization" : "the-road-to-learn-react",
  "repository" :"the-road-to-learn-react-chinese",
  "withFork" : true
}
```

The problem is on "withFork" saying

> ""message": "Variable $withFork is used by OrganizationForFacebook but
> not declared"

But haven't I declared it right there? What is the problem then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only declared two variables as part of your operation:

```
$organization: String!, $repository: String!
```

You need to add `$withFork: Boolean!` as well

Comment: Oh at the top.  OK I added it. Thanks. works now.    GraphQL is such a nice invention! I am enjoying learning it.